# Вывести на экран кол-во групп (определенное имя группы) для кажого курса

Tags: sql, sql-server

групы задаються в таком стиле км-13-1, КИ-13-1, где 13 - это год поступления (2013) ,а 1 это какая группа, соответственно может быть и  КИ-13-2   .

```
@DAT SMALLDATETIME
SET @DAT = getdate()
select   [group].name_group  , (substring([group].name_group,1,5)) as 'Код группы', 

case 
    when(year(@DAT)%100 - cast(substring(/*Num_group*/ [group].name_group, 4, 2) as int)=0) then 1   
    else 0
end
+(year(@DAT)%100 - (cast(substring(/*Num_group*/ [group].name_group, 4, 2) as int)))
+case
    when (month(@DAT) >= 9) then 1
    else 0
end
[Курс] 
        from [group] /* group by*/  order by [group].name_group
```

вот то что я набросал

и вот результат 
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

нужно чтобы оно как то группировало по первым 5 символам и брало последнюю строку из группы , а потом отсеивало первые 6 символов и мы получаем кол-во (пример: КИ-13-3 убераем первые 6 символов и получаем 3 , значит всего 3 группы ). Не знаю как реализовать

Comment: а что мешает группировать по `substring(name_group,1,5)` и вызывать `count(*)`? Ну кроме возможного существования групп из трех букв и необходимости работать со строками.

Comment: Не получаеться группировать так

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отрезаете от строки с названием последний символ *(функция substring, ее вы уже использовали)*, далее подсчет уникальных значений с группировкой:

```
Select 
substring([group].name_group,1,5) as 'Код_группы'
,COINT(DISTINCT substring( [group].name_group, 6, 1)) 
From... 
Group by substring([group].name_group,1,5)
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32406/discussion-on-answer-by-sanek-zhitnik-------).